# Nuxt.js routing middleware issue if target is set to 'static'

Tags: routes, static, nuxt.js, middleware

target: 'static' and router middleware.

Hello,
we have an application built on nuxt v2.4.0 which uses mode: 'universal'.
After migration to nuxt 2.14.0 the app keeps working properly.
However, there is a warning appears during 'yarn generate' command execution:

```
mode option is deprecated. You can safely remove it from nuxt.config
```

the 'router' section of the nuxt.config.js is:

```
  router: {
    trailingSlash : true,
    middleware: 'noroute'
  },
```

and the middleware/noroute.js file:

```
import consola from 'consola'
export default function ({ redirect, route }) {
  consola.log('consola welcomes you')
    if (!route.name) {
      return redirect(302, "/not-found/")
    }
}
```

to build the app the following command is used:

```
$yarn generate && yarn start
```

the app perfectly starts and its behaviour is expected.

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ nuxt start

 WARN  mode option is deprecated. You can safely remove it from nuxt.config


   ╭───────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                       │
   │   Nuxt @ v2.14.12                     │
   │                                       │
   │   ▸ Environment: production           │
   │   ▸ Rendering:   server-side          │
   │   ▸ Target:      static               │
   │                                       │
   │   Listening: http://localhost:3000/   │
   │                                       │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────╯

ℹ Serving static application from dist/
```

when I'm trying to perform HTTP get a request to the page which does not exist the server response is perfect:

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:3000/page-that-does-not-exist
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /not-found/
Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2021 11:00:18 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

So far so good.
Now i'm trying to get rid of the annoying warning message appearing at nuxt generate call by adding the target: 'static' to the nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  target: 'static',
  //ssr: true,
  
  router: {
    trailingSlash : true,
    middleware: 'noroute'
  },
  ...
```

yarn generate && yarn start:

```
$ nuxt start

 WARN  mode option is deprecated. You can safely remove it from nuxt.config                                                                                                                            13:09:25


   ╭───────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                       │
   │   Nuxt @ v2.14.12                     │
   │                                       │
   │   ▸ Environment: production           │
   │   ▸ Rendering:   server-side          │
   │   ▸ Target:      static               │
   │                                       │
   │   Listening: http://localhost:3000/   │
   │                                       │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────╯

ℹ Serving static application from dist/
```

but now curl returns HTTP status 200:

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:3000/page-that-does-not-exist
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2021 11:10:21 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

It looks like the routing flow has been changed recently.

Based on the info from the [article](https://kontent.ai/blog/demystify-nuxt-target-mode-and-ssr-properties)
mode: 'universal' option is an equivalent of 2 options target: 'static' and ssr: true (ssr:true is set by default so it can be omitted).
However, it does not work this way.

There is another good [article](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/09/10/the-new-target-static-mode-in-nuxt/) about static mode deployment to Netlify.
The solution from it does not work either.

My question is: what is the correct configuration for Nuxt.js v2.14.0 which 100% matches the universal mode in the previous versions,
or, maybe, the better question: what is the right way to get routing middleware to work with target: static.

Appreciate any kind of information which helps me resolving the issue

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the similar issue is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`mode: 'universal'` is equivalent to `target: 'server'` which is the default now.

That means you can safely remove `mode`, `target` and `ssr` options from your `nuxt.config.js` if you want to achieve server side rendering.

More information here:

- https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/deployment-targets